# How to restore grub2 after failed burg installation?

Tags: grub2, burg

I'm using 12.04 and few minutes ago I tried to install **`burg`** according to [this guide](http://www.overclock.net/t/1251224/guide-installing-burg-and-super-boot-manager-in-ubuntu-inc-12-04-lts).

I followed everything till the line `burg-emu` and there, I saw this `minimal bash-like line editing is supported`.

I installed burg to `hda` (because there was an error message [bad idea] when I tried this to the partition reserved for `grub2`.

Answer (score 7):

Boot into the Ubuntu Live CD and run a few commands in a new Terminal window.

First, identify which is the Ubuntu partition:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

Next, mount it (replacing **sda2** with the appropriate partition number):

```
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
```

And finally, reinstall Grub (replacing **sda** with the appropriate hard drive):

```
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
```

Now, run this:

```
sudo update-grub
```

This should detect your Ubuntu installation and add it to the Grub menu.

Reboot without the CD, and Grub should now load Ubuntu!

Comment: Yeah, worked perfectly :D

Comment: Great! Please consider [accepting the answer or upvoting it](http://askubuntu.com/faq#howtoask), in order to prevent it from showing up in the *Unanswered* section of the site. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks! Found this as a solution to something unrelated through Google - good work!