# System Hangs on Boot after BURG Install

Tags: dual-boot, bootloader, burg

I installed burg using [these instructions](http://www.unixmen.com/how-to-install-burg-boot-loader-in-ubuntu-1304-and-linuxmint/). `burg-emu` worked fine, the burg interface worked great, and I can still boot windows correctly.

When I boot linux (recovery or normal), I get the linux splash, but **after the last lines of my boot log my machine is just frozen**.

I tried [reverting the bootloader](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191072/how-to-restore-grub2-after-failed-burg-installation) to grub from the live USB. Despite an [error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254491/failed-to-get-canonical-path-of-cow) (about 'the canonical path for /cow'), I now get the old grub interface, but same broken boot.

Maybe I missed the `burg-install` step? Hopefully the issue is more obvious to someone else, please pull me out of this rabbit hole!

(Ubuntu 14.04)